# replace form after submit with ajax

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I managed to get my `ajax` request up and running, and now I want to dismiss the form based on the response that come back from my controller action. anyway enough of talking, I have something in these lines:

controller action:

```
public IActionResult Create(MyviewModel model)
{
   if(!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
     return BadRequest(ModelState);
   }

   var r = _context.Save(model);

    if(r.IsError) 
       prepare error message and send them back

   return OK(r.Data);
}
```

razor:

```
<form asp-controller="MyController" asp-action="Create" data-ajax" data-ajax-method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Email"></label>
    <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Comment"></label>
    <input asp-for="Comment" class="form-control">
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I am able to hit my action method without refreshing my URL. I can process the request, that's fine. But how do i get back the response and act accordingly? I gathered that `data-ajax-success` and `-failure` could be my friends but I have no idea how.

I basically want to replace the form on success with something like:

```
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Comment successfully submitted</div>.
```

In case of error, read the errors that are coming back from the server, and alert the user. in this case keep the form in case a user can try again.

I'm quite new in this javascript world, anyone to provide a minimal working solution or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stay out of javascript code if you prefer so.

Add the `data-ajax-mode` and `data-ajax-update` attributes to the form tag as in the example.

From your controller, return a PartialView after you set the correct message.

```
<div id="myDiv">
    @if (ViewBag.SuccessMessage != null)
    {
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">@Html.Raw(ViewBag.SuccessMessage)</div>
    }
    else
    {
        <form asp-controller="MyController" asp-action="Create" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#myDiv">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Email"></label>
                <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Comment"></label>
                <input asp-for="Comment" class="form-control">
            </div>
            @if (ViewBag.ErrorMessage != null)
            {
                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">@Html.Raw(ViewBag.ErrorMessage)</div>
            }
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
    }
</div>
```

In your form post action, set the correct message and return the same View as PartialView.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(MyviewModel model)
{
   if(!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Input not valid!";
       return PartialView(model);
   }

   var r = _context.Save(model);

    if(r.IsError) 
    {
       ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Error when saving...";
       return PartialView(model);
    }

    ViewBag.SuccessMessage = "Created successfully!";
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

Comment: Great :). and there I was crossing my fingers and toes that there must be non-js solution. If I understand well, I'll have to create a separate `partilaView` file. how will I include it the first time the parent view load as I will need the initial form?

Comment: No need to create a separate PartialView. Replace your View with the Razor of the answer. On Get, you return View, but on post, you return PartialView.

Comment: I updated the answer. I am assuming your View is called Create.cshtml and exists on the folder that has the same name as the Controller.

Comment: @JoãoPereira do you know if we have `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax` cdn sitting somewhere or (why microsoft doesn't host it on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/ajax/cdn/overview)?

Comment: @edit Never noticed it... I bundle my libraries on the solution, so never needed it in CDN. Nevertheless, I found it bundled to MVC v3.0 [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/ajax/cdn/overview#ASPNET_MVC_Releases_on_the_CDN_16). It's a little old, but small changes were made...

Comment: Thanks. I'll also have it `bower`-ed into my solution as a `asp-fallback-src`. Searching around I came accros https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.ajax.unobtrusive/3.2.4/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js

Comment: Not trying to hijack my own question here, but is also possible to fire an ajax on click to send some data (2 values), but still go to URL i specify in href? or will I have to go with normal js/jquery and listen to the clicks?

Comment: Send them to a different URL or the same URL? You can add more properties that don't belong to the object in the method, and they will also be posted `public IActionResult Create(MyviewModel model, string prop1, int prop2)`. If it's to a different URL, you will have to use js/jquery to get the values and send them.

Comment: it's actually a different URL (i.e. a different controller) than the one in the actual href